# How to check if object in nested array contains a value

Tags: python

In Python, this works:

```
for site in userSites:
  for role in site.roles:
    if role.role == Role.ADMIN:
        return True
return False
```

I am looking for a way to do this in a single line that can check a nested array to see if any of the user's sites contain the admin role.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in single line you can do this as below

```
return any(role.role == Role.Admin for site in userSites for role in site.roles)
```